# Brake pad doesn't fully contact disc

Tags: ford, brakes, brake-rotor, escort, brake-pad

My brake pads don't appear to fully contact the disc. They extend past the disc. [image: brake pad extending past disc]

Is this normal? Did I get the wrong size brake pads?

I don't recall ever having this problem before. I am also noticing a grinding noise occasionally yet the brakes have plenty of life left on them.

Make/model: 99 Ford escort

Comment: That is some dirty pad and disk assembly. Do you mean to say that the pads are "wider" than the disk, and therefore part of the pads will not be used when braking?

Comment: What make, model and year is this car?

Comment: That is unusual. Pads usually don't align that far out on the rotor. Did you compare them to the pads you removed? Like cdunn asked, what make and model of vehicle?

Comment: I replaced them a while back I only just inspected them and noticed the pads don't align with the disc. So I don't have the old ones to compare. Also added the make and model to the question

Comment: Are they sticking out past the top of the rotor, I can't tell? If they are, as they wear, the tops will reach towards each other over the rotor and may eventually touch at the end of the life of the pads. This is not ideal.

Comment: I'd take issue with your assessment that "the brakes have plenty of life left on them" as I'd say the rotors pictured are overdue for replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The brake rotors are damaged beyond repair by rust. The vent holes are full of rust. This causes the rotors to not cool well enough which can lead to burned spots, warping, pad material overheat and/or pad material transfer to the rotor surface. 
The pad hanging out over the outer diameter a little bit is not a problem for brake effectiveness.  It can lead to noise and premature wear and should be repaired. The pad outer edge should stop at about 2mm from the outer edge.

So the solution here is to replace the brake rotors and new pads. The pads could be reused if the new rotors happen to have a slightly large diameter and show no signs of overheating or other damage.

Answer (score 0):

The brake pads should not stick out past the rotor, period!

If they do and they are the correct pads, you will have to replace your rotors. I would never put used pads on with new rotors.

You also need a new caliper, it's sticking or stuck.